# Divisions and Parentheses

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

You may put as many parentheses  as possible to the below equation:

$1\div 2\div 3\div 4\div 5\div 6\div 7\div 8\div 9$

What is the maximum result you can have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biggest I've found:

> $1\div (2\div 3\div 4\div 5\div 6\div 7\div 8\div 9)$ $=$ $90720$

I believe this is also the largest

Answer (score 1):

Making use of the [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) tag:

> 1÷(2÷3÷4÷5÷6÷7÷8÷9 **)( ()** ) == infinite
>  ___________times-----^_^----zero

By (one) definition, the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make use of the [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) tag by saying

> "maximum result" means maximum digits. In which case
> (1÷2)÷3÷(4÷5÷6÷7÷8)÷9 = 7.777777777... repeating infinitely

Answer (score 0):

Since Beastly Gerbil clearly has the mathematically correct answer I'll use the [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) tag to get 14 instead.

> `1÷(2÷(3÷(4÷(5÷(6÷(7÷(8÷9)))))))`
>  The maximum number of meaningful parenthesis you can add is 14.